# How to get document library view from web part on SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, web-part, document-library, document

I currently have a document web part on my home page with a few folders with documents in each of them. When I click on the folders, the documents show as they should. However, I would like when I click on the folders, that it would link to the document page (takes up the whole page and shows the documents), instead of showing the documents in the quadrant that I currently have it in? Is that possible to do? I know when I click on the "Documents" Web part title, it does go to the documents page, but I would like the folders to direct to the page as well. Help please..

Answer (score 0):

If you want these kind of web part, you must code it. There is not any OOTB web part which directing to the SP library folders.

Probably you can try use *Search Content Query - Web-Part*.

- Source: Your Library
- Filter: ContentType - Folders & Url: First Level

this way you will have links on Folder Names to the library, but you must try it if it suits your vision.

Comment: Try, if you'll need some help I will be here tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I have understood your question properly, but, if you want to show the documents without the folders then you can create a new view and choose 'Show all items without folders' option to flatten it out. Like below.

[image: create view-folder options]

Let me know if you are looking for something else, and share a screenshot if possible.